# How do I use a ShowProgressAsync progress bar outside of the mainwindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, progress-bar, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to show a progress bar while i'm searching through the words in a string.  I know there's easier ways to search through strings, but I'm trying to show a simple example of what I want without tons of code.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace testProgressBars
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        bool isTextBox1Set = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public class DocumentSearch
        {
            public string searchTerm { get; set; }
            string myString = "this is a text string that I wanted to search through.";

            //This would be async if what I was trying was possible.
            public void SearchDoc()
            {
                int wordCount = myString.Split().Length;

                string[] words = myString.Split(' ');
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (word == searchTerm)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("yep....it's in here");
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        MessageBox.Show("nope.....it's not in here."); 
                    }
                    //I want my progress bar to update here....but this won't work.
                    //var progressBar = await this.ShowProgressAsync("wait for it", "finding words");
                    //progressBar.SetProgress((double)counter / (double)wordCount * 100);

                }

            }
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                Button1.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Button1.IsEnabled = false;
            }

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //get the word inside of the text field


            DocumentSearch docSearch = new DocumentSearch();
            docSearch.searchTerm = TextBox1.Text;
            docSearch.SearchDoc();


        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="testProgressBars.MainWindow"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Name ="StackPanel1" Margin="50">
            <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Height="25" Width="100" TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"/>
            <Button Name="Button1" Content="Go" IsEnabled="False" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="50" Click="Button1_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

I'm not sure how to show the progress bar from the DocumentSearch class since I think the problem with the current code is that the ShowProgressAsync needs to be connected to the MainWindow class somehow.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the MahApps library, but I feel that the basic issue is that you should not be doing any UI stuff in the `DocumentSearch`. Instead, it should provide hooks to allow the caller to receive progress reports and manage the dialog itself. For example:

```
    public class DocumentSearch
    {
        public string searchTerm { get; set; }
        string myString = "this is a text string that I wanted to search through.";

        //This would be async if what I was trying was possible.
        public async Task<bool> SearchDoc(IProgress<double> progress)
        {
            int wordCount = myString.Split().Length;

            string[] words = myString.Split(' ');
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                counter++;
                if (word == searchTerm)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                progress.Report((double)counter / (double)wordCount * 100);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Called like this:

```
    private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var progressBar = await this.ShowProgressAsync("wait for it", "finding words");
        IProgress<double> progress =
            new Progress<double>(value => progressBar.SetProgress(value));

        //get the word inside of the text field

        DocumentSearch docSearch = new DocumentSearch();
        docSearch.searchTerm = TextBox1.Text;
        bool result = await docSearch.SearchDoc(progress);

        MessageBox.Show(result ? "yep....it's in here" : "nope.....it's not in here.");
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you.  Answered more questions than I asked.